# Graph Implementation in Java using adjacency list

Tags: java, graph

I am building a Graph class to learn and eventually plan to add Dijkstra's algorithm to this implementation. 
What do you think of the overall approach? Any feedback on how to improve this?

**Vertex.java** - contains all vertex information

```
public class Vertex {
    int key;
    String name;

    protected Vertex(String name, int key) {
        this.name = name;
        this.key = key;
    }

    protected int getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    protected void setKey(int key) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    protected String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

**Graph.java** - edges are directed

```
public class MyGraph {
    HashMap<String, Vertex> vertexes = new HashMap<>();
    List<HashSet<Vertex>> adjList = new LinkedList<>();
    int index = 0;

    public void addVertex(String name) {
        if (!vertexes.containsKey(name)) {
            Vertex v = new Vertex(name, index);
            vertexes.put(name, v);
            index++;
            adjList.add(new HashSet<>());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Vertex " + name + " already exists in graph.");
        }
    }

    // v1 has directed edge towards v2
    public void addEdge(String name1, String name2) {
        // are both vertexes already in the graph?
        if (!vertexes.containsKey(name1) || !vertexes.containsKey(name2)) {
            System.out.println("Please enter vertexes that already exist in the graph.");
            return;
        }
        Vertex source = getVertex(name1);
        Vertex destination = getVertex(name2);

        // does edge already exist?
        int key = source.getKey();
        if (adjList.get(key).contains(destination)) {
            System.out.println("Edge from " + name1 + " to " + name2 + " already exists.");
            return;
        } else {
            adjList.get(key).add(destination);
        }
    }

    // removes all vertexes/edges from graph
    public void clear() {
        vertexes = new HashMap<>();
        adjList = new LinkedList<>();
        index = 0;
    }

    public HashSet<Vertex> getNeighbors(String name) {
        Vertex v = getVertex(name);
        Iterator iterator = adjList.get(v.getKey()).iterator();
        HashSet neighbors = new HashSet();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            neighbors.add(iterator.next());
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    private Vertex getVertex(String name) {
        return vertexes.get( name);
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return index == 0 && vertexes.isEmpty() && adjList.isEmpty();
    }

    public void removeEdge(String name1, String name2) {
        if (!containsVertex(name1) || !containsVertex(name2)) {
            System.out.println("Please check your inputs: at least one is invalid and dne in graph.");
            return;
        }
        Vertex v1 = getVertex(name1);
        Vertex v2 = getVertex(name2);
        adjList.get(v1.getKey()).remove(v2);
    }

    public void removeVertex(String name) {
        // before removing vertex
        // iterate over this.adjList
        //  1. remove all neighbors (hashset) from this.adjList
        //  2. need to remove all incoming edges from other vertexes
        //  3. update keys for all vertexes that come after one to be removed
        // 4. remove from HashMap this.vertices
        // 5. index--;
        if (!containsVertex(name)) {
            System.out.println("Vertex does not exist.");
            return;
        }
        Vertex v  = getVertex(name);
        int key = v.getKey();

        // remove vertex neighbors list from adjacency list
        adjList.remove(key);

        // remove references to vertex as a neighbor
        Iterator adjListIterator = adjList.iterator();
        while (adjListIterator.hasNext()) {
            HashSet neighborList = (HashSet) adjListIterator.next();
            if (neighborList.contains(v)) {
                neighborList.remove(v);
            }
        }

        // update keys for all vertexes that come after this
        if (key < size() - 1) {
            Iterator vertexIterator = vertexes.values().iterator();
            while (vertexIterator.hasNext()) {
                Vertex vertex = (Vertex) vertexIterator.next();
                int vertexKey = vertex.getKey();
                if (vertexKey > key) {
                    vertex.setKey(vertexKey-1);
                }
            }
        }
        vertexes.remove(name);
        index--;
    }

    // returns the number of vertexes
    public int size() {
        return vertexes.size();
    }

    public boolean containsVertex(String name) {
        Vertex v = getVertex(name);
        return (v != null && adjList.get(v.getKey()) != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the field `index` in `MyGraph` is redundant, because it only stores the number of vertexes which is already reflected by the size of `vertexes` and `adjList`. Having a property stored multiple times makes code confusing and fragile, because a bug could cause the respective fields to contain contradictory vaules.

Also, I don't think `key` should be a field of `Vertex`, because the way you use it, it is not a property of a vertex, but only a value that's associated with a vertex by a graph, so while the field `key` makes sense in the context of a graph, it is meaningless when considering a vertex alone. Now, removing the field `key` from `Vertex` reduces `Vertex` to a useless wrapper class for a `String`, so you might as well scratch the vertex class and simply store the vertexes directly as `String`s in `MyGraph`.

Now, about the purpose of `Vertex.key`. Theoretically, it represents the order in which the vertexes were added to the graph, but in your code, it only serves to associate the vertexes in `MyGraph.vertex` with the edges in `MyGraph.adjList`. Again, this makes the code fragile, because a bug could cause `adjList` to contain a set of edges at an index `i` that's not meant for the vertex with the key `i`. Instead, you could store the vertexes in a `Map<String, Set<String>>` (I'll just use `String` instead of `Vertex` as per my earlier suggestion), and if you want to preserve the order in which the vertexes were added to the graph, you can use a `LinkedHashMap`. That way, the relationship between vertexes and their neighbors is expressed directly by the code rather than an arbitrary correlation between an `int` field and the index in a list.

Next, your method `getNeighbors(String)` can be simplified. First of all, instead of creating an empty `HashSet` and then manually adding every element from a different `HashSet`, you could just invoke the constructor `HashSet(Collection<? extends E>)` instead of the no-argument-constructor (also, I suggest you avoid using raw types, because generics provide additional compile-time type-safety). Besides, there's an even better alternative: `Collections.unmodifiableSet​(Set<? extends T>)`. The advantage of this method is that the returned `Set` will not be modifiable directly, but it will still reflect changes to the original map, so you might think of it not as a "copy", but rather as a "read-only access". In this case, you might want to rename the method to `viewNeighbors` (although I'm not sure whether this is really more descriptive or just a personal habit of mine).

Also, I see that you are using a `LinkedList` for `adjList`, even though you are mostly performing `get` operations on it, and `ArrayList.get(int)` is *O(1)* while `LinkedList.get(int)` is *O(n)* (where *n* is the list size). Only in `removeVertex(String)` do you remove an element from it, but keep in mind that, while deleting an element from a `LinkedList` per se is *O(1)*, `LinkedList.remove(int)` first has to traverse the list to find the element, which is *O(n)*, while `ArrayList.remove(int)` would find the element in *O(1)* and remove it in *O(n)*. True, removing an element from an `ArrayList` can be slow for very large lists, slower than finding an element in a `LinkedList`, but unless you intend to create gigantic graphs with hundred thousands of vertexes where you continually remove vertexes in a loop, I doubt you would gain anything from using a `LinkedList`. Also, `ArrayList.add(E)` is *O(1)* unless the internal array must be resized, in which case it will be *O(n)*.

Finally, you are mixing up user interface with program logic by including all those `System.out.println` statements. I think it would be better to throw exceptions whenever appropriate (like an `IllegalArgumentException`, for example) and let the calling method handle it. After all, a graph doesn't care whether an attempt to add a vertex or an edge was executed via the command line or by some other erroneous code.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you for the comments! I've updated my implementation to remove the index field, the vertexes HashMap, and the Vertex class entirely. Now I am using a HashMap<String<Set<String>> as the adjacency list, and no longer need to have a key or an index to refer to a vertex's neighbors. Changes in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/192694/graph-implementation-in-java-using-adjacency-list-v2